# Error while loading a basic react-leaflet map

Tags: react-leaflet

I am new to react-leaflet.
I'm working on a Flask React project and I'm trying to load a react-leaflet map.
I'm getting the below error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default' in undefined
at react-leaflet.js:7
at React__default (react-leaflet.js:4)
at react-leaflet.js:5
```

Versions :

react-leaflet : v1.9.1
leaflet.css : v1.3.1
react-leaflet.js : v1.9.1

I have added the necessary routes for rendering the Appbody.
But I'm unable to figure out what is wrong.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer} from 'react-leaflet'

const position = [51.505, -0.09]

class MainMap extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <Map center={position} zoom={13}>
     <TileLayer
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
     />
     <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>
       <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br/>Easily customizable.</span>
      </Popup>
     </Marker>
    </Map>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default MainMap;
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MainMap from "./map";

class AppBody extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <MainMap/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default AppBody;
```

```css
.leaflet-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using react-leaflet and I never had this kind of error, but I can see something wrong in the code (I don't know if those resolve the problem). 
Firstly have you imported the leaflet.css file? You need to import this in the index.js or in the current file 
`import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";`
You have also to add a ref props in the map component like this 
`<Map ref = "map" {...otherprops} >`

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem in your code is surrounding the Map element by **div tags**. 
So if you remove them and make the Map element at the top, then the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Do not include the react-leaflet CDN in your index.html if you have installed it with npm or yarn.

---

Well, after much probing around with the problem myself I think you may have set up things incorrectly in the `<head>` of your index.html, this is how I had it set up *before* with the error happening:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-leaflet/2.0.0/react-leaflet.js"></script>
```

and solving the issue:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
crossorigin=""/>
```

Notice the difference? If you have installed `react-leaflet` with `npm` or `yarn`, you'll see that you don't need to add the leaflet script in your `<head>`. What was happening before is that the react-leaflet script was loading before the webpacked js files and it therefore could not find React. The react-leaflet source code that threw the error looked like this:

```
var React__default = 'default' in React ? React['default'] : React;
```

And obviously, if there was no React object in the first place, there will be an error when trying to find the 'default' key.

Hope this helps someone some day!